# NGINX 502 Bad Gateway with node app

Tags: nginx, server

I'm having a problem with [my website](http://www.maisonlegrand.com/).The site is down error "502 Bad Gateway" from nginx. I restarted the server and there are no errors. The site ran for months and now there is this error.

The node app is still running. Nothing changes there. The website is hosted on digitalocean and everything seems fine.

Site is located `home/naoufal/mlg` not inside `www`

**app.js**

`var port = process.env.PORT || 8888;`

**sites-available/default**

```
server {

        root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        index index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to index.html
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
        }
       location /doc/ {
                alias /usr/share/doc/;
                autoindex on;
                allow 127.0.0.1;
                deny all;
        }
}
```

**nginx.config**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

        # server_tokens off;
        server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;


        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        ##
        # nginx-passenger config
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
        ##

        #passenger_root /usr;
        #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

       ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

What's wrong?

Thanks.

**Edit: The site is now working for no particular reason. I think it was a problem with Digital Ocean not on the code itself.**

Comment: Will be good to see nginx config and understand how you run node app.

Comment: Update. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Provided configs have nothing related to node app. Can you share file, specific to your app, it should be inside `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`, `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`...